# How to make a daily notification at 8 am? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notifications

I'm sorry to ask you for something like that, but I've tried this in five different ways and none of them worked. I'm currently working on an app that gives you everyday, when you awake, a little notification with an interesting fact. It takes those facts from an array that is set. I've tried to use UNNotificationCenter, UILocalNotification, etc. but I didn't succeed in writing that function. I would be glad if you could help me out with this code!

So, at 8 am, the App has to

1. Call the function that gives it a new fact from the array and store it in UserDefaults, lets call it `newFact()`
2. Make a notification that appears on 8 am every day, also if the phone is locked

I would be very thankful if you could help me!

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code

You can call the function here

```
let fact = self.newfact()
UserDefaults.standard.set(fact,forKey: "fact")


var dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
            dateComp.year = 2017;
            dateComp.month = 04;
            dateComp.day = 05;
            dateComp.hour = 08;
            dateComp.minute = 00;
            dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

        var calender:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        var date:NSDate = calender.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!

        var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.category = "Daily alarm "
        notification.alertBody = fact
        notification.fireDate = date
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
```

Comment: what about showing new text each time the notification is fired?

Comment: you can use as variable that can be find by date  lets say you have dictionary {date:body}  notification.alertbody = dict[date]

Comment: Thank you, already, but the problem is that I NEED to call that function since it first takes a random number and then inserts it as index. And I have to save it to UserDefaults.

Comment: Where can I insert a line of code that refers to my function? :/

Comment: Can you show your function and what you need to send to alert body

Comment: @Whazzup Edited the answer please check.